# Types conversion between different types in an implicit manner

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, type-conversion

I need an in implicit conversion from A* to C*;
i cannot change A's definition or implementation.

```
class A
{
};

struct B: public A
{
};

struct C: public B
{

};
```

when i write the following:

```
A* p;
C* q = p;
```

i am getting an error C2440; cannot convert from A* to C*.
what can i do giving the fact i cannot change A. both classes are plain structs of primitive data.

Comment: If you can alter C, you can make a conversion constructor that takes an A*.  If you're absolutely possitive that the A is actually a C, you can use dynamic_cast<C*> or static_cast<C*>  If A is not a C, rethink what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can do this is to use a cast:

```
// a C++ style static_cast:
C* q = static_cast<C*>(p);

// or the less verbose C-style cast
C* q = (C*)p;
```

Because `C` is a derivative of `A` and **not every `A` is a `C`**, it cannot be implicitly casted (like you could implicitly cast a `C*` to an `A*` because **every `C` is an `A`** (i.e. `A` has "less or equal features" than `C`, but not more)).

I doubt that you really *must have* an implicit cast between pointer types. What is it making you think you do?

Comment: C is an extended structure of A where the extension part is used internall by C only. And the assignment part should only assign the match members of C and A.

Comment: @sramij what does that have to do with needing an implicit cast? And pointers don't work that way; you can't "only assign the matching members of A". If you wanted to cast an _object_ (not a pointer), you could define a conversion operator. But you cant do that for pointers.